# slick navigation issues to the foreign keys (after joinLeft)

Tags: scala, foreign-keys, slick

```
val joined =  A joinLeft B on (_.id === _.id)

 val query  = for {
   (A, BOpt) <- joined
 } yield (A.a, BOpt.map(_.b))
```

So far so good.

B has a foreign key relationship(def FK_R) --> C. I'd like to navigate to C.c

BOpt is Rep[Option[B]]. How do I access table B so I can navigate to C.
Something like BOpt.FK_R.c

(There's also C-> D, but let's skip that.)
In a nutshell, I need A.a, B.b, C.c, D.d